# Weak and strong completeness

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, pseudo-polynomial

What does a pseudo-polynomial algorithm tell us about the problem it solves? I don't see how running time improves if the algorithm is exponential in the input length and polynomial in the input value; so how do we explain this shift from exponential to polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by "improves"? Relative to what?

Comment: @Raphael Where does the polynomial part come from?

Answer (score 6):

As it is stated in "[Computers and Intractability: a Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716710455)" A pseudo-polynomial-time algorithm will display '**exponential behavior**' only when confronted with instances containing '**exponentially large**' numbers, which might be rare for the applications we are interested in. If so, this type of algorithm might serve our purposes almost as well as a polynomial time algorithm.”

You can consider [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) as a good example of **[weakly-Np Complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_NP-complete)**. In this case the complexity of the dynamic programming solution is $O(nW)$ which is well in most **practical** cases.

It is known that there is no pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for [**Strong NP-Complete**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete) problems (like [Steiner Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem)) unless P=NP.

Comment: Does this mean that pseudopolynomial algorithms work for problems that take numerical inputs (as implied from your answer)?

Comment: @saadtaame: Yes, the key point is that they are numerical problems in which the running time is related to the numerical input data.

Answer (score 1):

This answer pertains to *quasipolynomial* algorithms rather than *pseudopolynomial* ones.

A quasipolynomial algorithm tells us that the problem is probably not NP-hard. The (somewhat) commonly-believed Exponential Time Hypothesis (ETH) states that 3SAT on $n$ variables requires time $2^{\Omega(n)}$. Since 3SAT is in NP, the ETH implies that any NP-complete problem requires time $2^{n^{\Omega(1)}}$, which grows faster than quasipolynomial (assuming by the latter is meant $2^{\log^{O(1)} n}$).

Comment: But there are plenty of NP-hard problems with pseudo-polynomial algorithms.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: pseudo-polynomial is not assuming:  $2^{\log^{O(1)} n}$ it has very clear definition. Also I didn't see such an assumption anywhere, whould you provide any reference? Also Raphael is right, for all problems which are belong to weakly np-compelete (means they are also np-hard) there is pseudo polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: Pseudo-polynomial means different things to different people. As to the exponential time hypothesis, google has quite a file on it.

Comment: Question title is: "Weak and strong completeness", Also if I claim something, usually I'll provide reference for my claim, I don't know about you, but, because I think in this way even if someone else is right, I expect to prove it himself, but yes, you are free to claim something and say if you don't believe it research it yourself.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the question carefully. But I promise you that pseudo-polynomial sometimes means what I wrote, and the ETH is pretty commonplace (even Wikipedia has some information on it, which I consulted prior to writing the answer).

Comment: I think is better to delete this answer, because is actually confusing for OP, also still I cannot see any relation between ETH and pseudo-polynomial time, and worst thing in your answer is: $2^{\log^{O(1)} n}$ which is $O(n^{O(1)})$, and I think you where looking for something like $O(2^{n^\epsilon})$.

Comment: No, actually $2^{O(\log n)} = n^{O(1)}$, $2^{\log^{O(1)} n}$ is quasipolynomial (ah - that's the correct term!). The complexity class $2^{n^{O(1)}}$ is usually called subexponential.

Comment: ultimately you found correct term ;-)